# Deleting localstorage but still persists

Tags: android, android-webview, local-storage

I am attempting to clear the localstorage used by the webview in my application when the user logs out. I am manually deleting the folder which holds the localstorage and am able to verify that it gets deleted when the user logs out. However when they log back in, the localstorage still seems to be accessible to the webview even though there are no localstorage files. If I manually kill the process after logging out it works as intended but I need this behaviour without killing the application.

Is it possible to clear the RAM used by the application, is this a known bug with the vebview, or is there some other way that I can solve this problem?

I have tried deleting the webview and webviewCache databases, deleting all the cache folders, deleting files used by the application but the localstorage still persists since the application is not reset when logged out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally found out what I was looking for!

Since we have a sort of built in browser in the app, there are many web pages that can be loaded and save things to localStorage. Calling `localStorage.clear()` or `loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.clear()")` were not properly clearing all caches for all web pages etc.

The behaviour that finally worked was using `WebStorage.deleteAllData()` linked below. I am also deleting the files (since kitkat it saves in app_webview by default, prior to that you provide the path)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html#deleteAllData()

Comment: Been looking for hours and nothing worked, until I saw your answer of using WebStorage.deleteAllData()
Thank you :)

Comment: You might need to use `WebStorage.getInstance().deleteAllData()`

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `localStorage.clear()` in JavaScript to clear localStorage, rather than jerking `WebView` around by deleting files that it manages.

Comment: I wont have control over the javascript files since they will be written by other developers and just hosted in my application's browser

Comment: @Mike: You should not need "control over the javascript files". Call `loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.clear()")` on your `WebView`.

Comment: What if I need to do it from my Application base where I do not have a reference to the webView, is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Mike: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: That is unfortunate. This solution also only seems to work the second time it is called, I will try moving the location that I call it and see if maybe that is my problem.

Comment: @Mike: Just call it before you call `loadUrl()` for the real content you put into the `WebView`. IOW, don't worry about clearing after logout; clear before login instead.

Comment: I attempted to do this in the onPageStarted since I will have to do it for each url that is being loaded by my webview (I am not sure if this is the correct place to do so) but it appears sometimes as though it takes two refreshes for the clearing to work. I would like eventually to keep a list of the URLs being loaded and only load this javascript on the initial load of each one but for now I am testing clearing it every time it loads