# Deleting local storage in WebView2

Tags: .net, webview2

---

I have a winforms app using the WebView2 SDK. In my application I'm loading a JavaScript based resource making heavy use of the brwosers local storage to save data.
However, I would like to be able, on a client basis, to control when the local storage is cleared (e.g. for the next user). Is there an API method to do this similar to the CoreWebView2.DeleteAllCookies() function? If not how can I go about this?

Deleting all content of the elements local storage would be all I need, there is no need for being selective.

Cheers!
Marc

Comment: [Is the answer on this post what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653916/deleting-localstorage-but-still-persists)?

Comment: Thank you so much! This pointed me to the solution! Have a great weekend!

Comment: Either add an answer or mark yours as duplicate.

Comment: Hey Andrew, not quite sure whether I get your comment or what to do..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting local storage

```
MyWebViewElement.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("javascript:localStorage.clear()")
```